# How to Redirect Laravel URL with Parameter in 5.0

Tags: php, laravel

I need to redirect an URL in the following format?

```
$id=5;
return Redirect::to('dashboard/{$id}');
```

Comment: What is thé question  ?

Comment: return Redirect::to('dashboard/'.$id); this should work

Answer (score 1):

You will need the route name or the Controller/Action name to redirect on a route with a parameter :

**PHP**

```
return redirect()->route('ROUTE_NAME', ['id' => 1]);
```

or

```
return redirect()->action('MyController@MyAction', ['id' => 1]);
```

Comment: You dont *need* this. It's handy, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would work fine if you just used `"` instead of `'`. Variables aren't interpreted within a single-quoted string in PHP.

```
 $id=5;
 return Redirect::to("dashboard/{$id}");
```